# Cloudfront X-Cache shows "Miss from cloudfront" all the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, api-gateway

I have a cloudfront web distribution setup for an API Gateway proxy. The API is IAM enabled mock call. I also created a customer name which has the same domain name as the cname I used to create cloudfront distribution.  I set cloudfront up to pass Authorization and Host only for headers. And set Query String forwarding and Forward Cookie to None.

When I hit the cloud front using Postman, I kept on getting **Miss from cloudfront** from the response. I also disabled Postman's `send no-cache header` and I also tried manually adding a `Cache-Control: max-age=3600`.

But None of these works.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: So you're sending multiple requests with exactly the same path and **exactly the same `Authorization` header** and still seeing cache misses?

Comment: Michael, I believe the Authorization changes because it's calculated based on a date. But that's what AWS signature V4 does. I am not sure how to change that. everything else is exact the same.

Comment: I think you are not guaranteed to hit the same edge location server on every request. When we are talking about just a few manually initiated requests, you may not see any caching. I think if you were to send a lot more requests (maybe hundreds of requests), or perhaps always resolve the hostname to the same IP address (maybe with the hosts file), that may finally help you see some caching take place. I hope you manage to solve it.

Comment: I think since we can't make sure Authorization is the same for each request, this setup simply is not feasible.

Comment: Are you sure you were making the request to cloudfront and not to api gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar issue by noticing that the API Gateway domain name for my RestAPI was always returning an **X-Cache** header with **"Miss from cloudfront"**; but after realizing I had used the execute api domain, my second request to my `*.cloudfront.net` domain resulted in a Cloudfront cache hit.